# using forfiles to delete files

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I have a simple line in a bat file. The line works perfect in a command window but when I add it to a bat file it does not do anything. The line that I am using in below.

```
forfiles -p E:\Apps\data\Upload-Copy -s -m *.* /d -120 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

My goal is that I have multiple locations that I would like to add to this bat file and set up a scheduled task to run it daily.

I have also tried this and it didn't work either.

```
ForFiles /p "E:\Apps\data\Upload-Copy" /s /d -120/c "cmd /c del /q @file"
```

I have tried with no luck again this works just by typing in Command prompt but not in the .bat file

%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "E:\Apps\data\Upload-Copy" /S /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C 0x22If @IsDir==FALSE Del /F /A @File0x22" /D -120

I have the bat file stored in the root of the C:drive and verified that the path is correct. I am just double clicking on the file C:\File2Delete.bat and the command prompt flashing on the screen for a second or less but does not delete any of the files

this will be on `Windows 2008 R2 server` and `Windows 2019 server`

Comment: At first, your line should read `forfiles /S /P "E:\Apps\data\Upload-Copy" /M * /D -120 /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE (del @file) else (2^> nul rd @file)"` since `forfiles` enumerates both files and directories; remove the portion `else (2^> nul rd @file)` if you want to leave behind empty directories; if you want to specify a general mask use `*` since `*.*` would not match files with no extension (due to specific handling of such wildcards by `forfiles`). To specify multiple locations I would wrap around a standard `for` loop…

Comment: The usage information for both your `forfiles` command and your `del` command are available at the Command Prompt, via `forfiles /?` and `del /?` respectively. First of all options are preceded with forward slashes, not hyphens. Additionally the option forward slash should be be preceded by a space character. The `/M` option is not needed, _(`*` is the default)_, and `Del`'s `/Q` isn't either. With those fixed, the only reason I could see for the matching files not deleting is that you do not have the required permissions to delete them, or that you've broken the `%PATH%` variable.

Comment: Another problem may be that you're running this as a scheduled task, and at the time you're running it, the drive `E:` is not mapped and available to the user under whom that task is being run. I would rewrite what you've submitted as `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "E:\Apps\data\Upload-Copy" /S /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C 0x22If @IsDir==FALSE Del /F /A @File0x22" /D -120`, try the batch file again and see if things change, then report  back. If it doesn't work, please [edit] your question to provide all of your Scheduled Task configuration settings.

Comment: @Compo: you mean `forfiles -p E:\Apps\data\Upload-Copy -s -m *.* /d -120 /c del`?

Comment: You are using the `/S` option. Which means files will be located in a sub folder. `@FILE` is only the file name. The `DEL` command will never find the file. You need to use `@PATH` with the `DEL` command.

Comment: @Dominique, no I do not, my commented command is exactly what I meant. Just because `forfiles` may accept `-`, the command help specifically shows `/`, so those should be used. The `/M` option, already defaults to `*` so isn't needed in this case _(all items)_, and `*.*` will only pick up files and directories with a period. Finally `Del` is internal to `cmd.exe`, so cmd is needed. Squashman, `@File` is fine, `@Path` isn't needed, `forfiles` recurses to each directory and makes it current for each `Del` command executed, so there is not need for the full path filename and extension to be used.

Comment: @Compo wow. I never knew that but just tested it and you were right.   I am not sure how it keeps track of that though. I would have thought doing `/C "cmd /c echo %CD%"` would echo the current working directory but it does not.  EDIT: AAH.  But this does show it. `/C "cmd /c cd"`.

Comment: @Squashman, I don't think internally it actually changes directory, otherwise, it wouldn't be able to remove it should you be using `If @IsDir==TRUE RD @file`, _(I haven't tried it however, and assume that would be valid, and as you know you cannot remove a current working directory)_, but it acts upon each as if it were. I'd expect that jeb, Aacini, dbenham etc. may know better about its internal workings. _I'll be honest, I wasn't aware of this for a long time, and thought it worked in exactly the same way as your comment had suggested_.